# Cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am having problems trying to run TensorFlow on my Windows 10 machine. Code runs fine on my MacOS machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Fynn\Documents\GitHub\AlpacaTradingBot\ai.py", line 15, in <module>
    from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
  File "C:\Users\Fynn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from keras import models
  File "C:\Users\Fynn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\models\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from keras.engine.functional import Functional
  File "C:\Users\Fynn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\functional.py", line 24, in <module>
    from keras.dtensor import layout_map as layout_map_lib
  File "C:\Users\Fynn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\dtensor\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental import dtensor as dtensor_api  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
ImportError: cannot import name 'dtensor' from 'tensorflow.compat.v2.experimental' (C:\Users\Fynn\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\_api\v2\compat\v2\experimental\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many solutions to no avail, in the end this worked for me!

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow absl-py astunparse flatbuffers gast google-pasta grpcio h5py keras keras-preprocessing libclang numpy opt-einsum protobuf setuptools six tensorboard tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem termcolor tf-estimator-nightly typing-extensions wrapt
```

```
pip3 install --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir tensorflow
```

Answer (score 38):

This can be caused by an incompatibility between your `tensorflow` and your `keras` versions. In particular I see this with `tensorflow==2.6.0` and `keras==2.9.0`, though I would not be surprised if other versions can cause this as well.

Either update your `tensorflow` version by:

```bash
pip install tensorflow==2.8
```

or downgrade your `keras` version by:

```bash
pip install keras==2.6
```

Comment: pip install tensorflow==2.8 will update keras unfortunately.

Comment: Yes upgrading my tensorflow to 2.8 fixed my wrapt and dtensor error, pip install tensorflow==2.8   this worked, thanks!

Comment: After a fresh installation of tensorflow 2.6.0 (on a Windows machine), using Keras 2.6 as suggested worked for me, simply by using `pip install keras==2.6`

Comment: thanks I've been been stuck in this for a while.  waymo open dataset strictly depends on tf 2.6 and that causes quite a lot package conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Just run :

```
pip install --disable-pip-version-check --no-cache-dir tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you must delete tensorflow and keras folder at site-package.
Open admin command prompt use this codes

```
pip uninstall tensorflow 

pip install tensorflow --ignore-installed
```